# Small indexing issue python

Tags: python

This program is supposed to return the first three letters of a list, such as `['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']` would return:

```
Mon  
Tue  
Wed  
Thu
```

This is my code:

```
def three(lst):  
    for i in lst:  
        return lst[:3]
```

I cannot get this to work, I found a similar question here that the answer did not work for, and my textbook is giving me nothing. Thanks!

Comment: `['Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday']` is a list with one string in it. You probably want to write `['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']`

Comment: I would recommend using an online tutorial, not a textbook.

Comment: Something like this maybe: https://www.learnpython.org/

Comment: Incidentally there is a more advanced construct in Python called `yield` that does something a little closer to what you want. But work on making sure you understand `return` before tackling `yield`.

Comment: @Iguananaut I have rolled back you edit to the title. You might be correct, but it is the OP that should clarify it.

Comment: I don't think that makes any sense. I used to ask OPs to improve their title but the problem with that is they often don't understand their own problem well enough to do that. This problem has nothing to with indexing

Comment: @Iguananaut it has, as you can see - `lst[:3]` is wrong, regardless of `return`/`print` issue. Right now the question is ambiguous, and you can't disambiguate it "destructively".

Comment: @OP: can you give a link to the similar question you've found?

Comment: That is true that it's ambiguous but I think one can disambiguate "destructively"

Comment: @Iguananaut this is misleading (and mislead my own voting and comments). You understand X, but you might be wrong, and you know you might be wrong. Please add your understanding in comments and answer. Don't rewrite the question.

Comment: There's no rule against that...or is there? "don't rewrite the question". I didn't rewrite the question, only the title. I think it's often helpful to rewrite the wording of a question, though you can disagree with my choice in this case. Anyways I don't want to spam the comments any more with this

Answer (score 2):

`return` exits the function at once. You have to collect the letters in a new list:

```
def three(lst):
    result = []
    for item in lst:
        result.append(item[:3])
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the first 3 letters of `i` not the elements of `lst`

```
def three(lst):  
    for i in lst:  
        print(i[:3])
```

Comment: This answer is (probably) correct, but the OP seems to struggle with basic notions of programming: what's does it mean to "return", to "print", to iterate using `for`, etc. I doubt these can be taught in a SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

In python we use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for tasks like these.

```
lst = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']

def three(lst):  
    return [i[:3] for i in lst]

three(lst)
```

Or yield to return a generator (a generator is basically a list that can only be used once):

```
def three(lst):  
    for item in lst:
        yield item[:3]

list(three(lst))
```

Return:

```
['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu']
```

---

**However** if your aim is only to print then we can simply do this:

```
print('\n'.join(i[:3] for i in lst))
```

this joins the elements with a row break from the list using a generator, it prints:

```
Mon
Tue
Wed
Thu
```